# От LiqPay приходит запрос с пустым массивом $_POST

Tags: php

День добрый
Платежная система после оплаты должна возвращать мне на мой server_url POST запрос с данными о платеже, но я почему то получаю пустой POST. Серверная страница у меня выглядит сейчас таким образом `<?php print_r($_POST);`. Пробовал через $_REQUEST, все равно пустой массив. Служба тех. поддержки liqpay говорит мне что запрос с их стороны успешно отправляется, и ошибка где-то у меня на серверной странице. Но где там может быть ошибка, если я просто хочу вывести массив. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой и может подсказать что-нибудь.

P.S. Ридеректов на странице нет. В форме запроса к liqpay указываю
<input type="hidden" name="result_url" value="http://www.мой_сайт/cms/fishka.php" />
<input type="hidden" name="server_url" value="https://www.мой_сайт/cms/fishka.php" />

Comment: 1. Нет ли у вас редиректа в htaccess с www на без www?
  2. Верно ли указан у вас адрес к файлу?
  3. Логируйте все обращения к сайту, чтобы понять по какому адресу обращается робот.